# Everything is locked

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I use Windows and Ubuntu as dual boots. All my files are locked and only folders are open. They also show a message as shown below. When the 'Fix Now' button is pressed, the password will be requested, but nothing will happen when it is given.

[image: Screen photo 1]

[image: Screen photo 1]

Comment: This looks like the file system is read only.  This is often a symptom of early hard drive failure. The system will change the file system to read only to prevent further damage to the file system.  Can you run the following command and edit your question with the output: `touch ~/Downloads/testfile`. This will attempt to create a blank file named `testfile` in your user's downloads folder.  If it fails, copy/paste there error in your question with an edit. If it succeeds, you can delete the file. Let us know either way. Tag me @nmath in a comment or I'll miss it

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Running a GUI file manager as root is dangerous. Some operations may change ownership and permissions to root in a way that can break things.*

This may not fix your problem, but you might unlock your files by running Nautilus with root privileges.

Try opening a terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type:

```
sudo nautilus
```

Enter password and navigate to your files.

While you are running nautilus as root, right click on the files to review the permissions.

Comment: @Nmath as long as you be cautious and don't modify any configuration files, it will be fine.

Comment: @Nmath true, its is still possible but indeed risky as everything will be set to root owner ship (i forgot about that, my bad)

Comment: @Nmath This isn't a great idea but not an awful idea.  Nowhere in this post did Noob say to do it to "every file" and thus "leave a trail of destruction".  That's a little dramatic but I did enjoy your word choice!  Having said that, rather than `sudo nautilus`, perhaps the OP can just `sudo cat` a single file to see if the issue is with permissions or with a locked file system due to a hard drive issue or something wrong with UIDs / permissions.

Comment: @Nmath nice edit, thank you!